# Rectangle not updating nor showing color

Tags: java, android, view, colors

I am having issues with by rectangle not stopping (hard coded values due to bugs with grabbing screen height) in addition, when I draw with red paint, I always get a black rectangle no matter what, any ideas?

If you need more code, let me know.

```
 public void draw(Canvas canvas){
        Rect rect;
        rect = new Rect(x, y, x + SIZE, y + SIZE);
        Paint paint = new Paint(Color.rgb(250, 0, 0));

       canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
    }

    public void update(){

        if (this.y < (1920 - SIZE)) {
            this.y += 5;
        } else if (this.y > 1920){
            this.y = 1920 - SIZE;
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`Paint(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#Paint(int))  constructor doesn't take a color value; those are actually flags.

Just use [`setColor(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setColor(int)) instead.

If you want it to animate, add a call to `invalidate()` to your `onDraw()` routine (doesn't really matter where). That way, it keeps getting redrawn, in an endless cycle. Also, call `update()` inside `onDraw()` as well. Kind of a "poor-man's" animation, but it should get you going.